# IntelliJ publigin: ghc-modi error output: NG quit

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea, ghc, ghc-mod

I'm just using GHC 7.8.4 and cabal 1.22.0.0 with IntelliJ Haskell plugin. After starting my project, I receive this error log

```
ghc-modi failed
          ghc-modi failed with error: NG BUG: cabal: createProcess: runInteractiveProcess: exec: does not exist (No such file or directory)
          You can disable ghc-modi in Settings | Haskell
IOException: Broken pipe
IOException: Broken pipe
```

How can I solve or get more information on this error?

Comment: Looks like you might not have it installed properly, can you confirm that it's installed properly and the `ghc-mod` and `ghc-modi` binaries are where IntelliJ can find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem on Mac OS X and solved it by launching IntelliJ IDEA with `open /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 14.app` shell command.

If you write some scripts for Haskell in `.bashrc`, it doesn't affect IntelliJ IDEA launched from Desktop or Launchpad e.t.c. Using `open` shell command let IntelliJ IDEA affected.